# How to use C Libraries for Arduino code

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a code in Visual studio that I want to implement in Arduino. But there is a problem. Many libraries usable in Visual Studio aren't usable in Arduino IDE. How can I use them in my Arduino code. To be precise, the libraries I want to use are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
```

respectively.

Okay so I know I have `<iostream>` available in Arduino. `<math.h>` is also available I think along with `<string>` library.

The main problem is to how to use `#include <queue>` and its functions such as `priority_queue()` and other fucntions of `iostream` like `.pop()`?

Comment: Libraries you want to use: `#include , #include , #include , #include , #include , #include`.  You may want to edit your question to include the actual header file names.

Comment: You can not. Just read an intro into Arduino. Also note that the Arduino language is neither C nor C++, so the tags are wrong here.

Comment: @rost0031 You were just blinded by inappropriate formatting.

Comment: Are you trying to access C language libraries from C++? Your question title asks about C libraries by the language tag is C++.

Comment: @OP Not these aren't different _libraries_, but header files bound to the c++ standard library implementation, that's coming with your c++ compiler.

Comment: @rost0031 Was pretty easy to fix it ...

Comment: Can you compile your Arduino code as C++?  *(I haven't played with the Arduino platform so I don't know on this one.  Other embedded systems have C++ compilers.)*

Comment: Welcome to the world of embedded development. Get used to not having access to everything and having to implement some things on your own.

Comment: Just a comment: stop thinking at uC as if they were PCs. They have very little performances! So if you REALLY need queues then go ahead and use them, but... I don't think you really need them. Instead of making a dynamic array, make a fixed one. Otherwise your uC will spend all of its life allocating and/or moving bytes in its memory instead of doing something useful...

Comment: I need dynamic queues. I'm implementing A star Algorithm in Arduino. It's really tough though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arduino behind the scenes is using the avr-gcc compiler, which provides support for many of the features of the C++ language. It does not, however, include an implementation of libstdc++, which means that a lot of the libraries and features you are used to having with other development environments are just not there. A big reason for this is that it is just not practical to implement some of that functionality on a small microcontroller.

There are several libraries available that implement simplified versions of some of the functions and data structures you are wanting to use. You can find a list (but not necessarily a complete one) of these libraries here:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList

For example QueueList might be a good alternative to `<queue>`.

Whatever you find, you are likely to have to refactor your code to use them. When you run into problems implementing those libraries and changes, I would recommend heading over to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ to get more arduino specific answers.

Comment: Thanks alot jack C that was really helpful, I'll update you once I implement them on my arduino code

Answer (score 1):

It is detailed over here:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess

> The include path includes the sketch's directory, the target directory
>   (/hardware/core//) and the avr include directory
>   (/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/), as well as any library
>   directories (in /hardware/libraries/) which contain a header
>   file which is included by the main sketch file.

And these are the libraries supported by avr-gcc (the compiler that Arduino uses)

http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html